# Allowed and opened port stopped working on GCP compute engine instance

Tags: linux, services

So, I had two instances of the same django application running on ports 8000 and 10001 (both opened on the linux instance and in the gcp firewall). 8000 hosted a testing environment and 10001 hosted a 'production' version of the django application.

The production instance got moved to port 80 and received a domain url, while the test remained on 8000. I haven't done any work on that in a while and just recently noticed that the test environment didn't work - as in it wouldn't load the web page, and continued to not work until I moved it to port 10001.

Why would the instance not work on port 8000? The only thing i've done on that linux instance since was to schedule a cron job which is currently disabled (in case it utilizes a port). Looking at nmap the only process using port 8000 was the service itself.

I am genuinely puzzled by this.